# Using Next.js and React for a DApp

Tags: dapps, react, mobile-wallet, nextjs

This is a more general question, but I've been trying to learn how to build DApps using Ethereum, and have noticed that most tutorials are using Next.js and React.js. What is the advantage of using these frameworks over something like React Native? I feel like many DApps are moving to mobile, so why do these tutorials still prefer using web frameworks if the trend is moving toward mobile?